# Play Framework class test runners -- test summary results not adding up

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

Does anyone know how I can configure test runner classes other than the default -- and get the test summary results to count tests run/failed correct?

Specifically, I want to run with a couple specialized runners.  For instance the spring junit runner:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
```

or perhaps the junit category runner:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
```

The tests annotated with the above run, but no results are printed out in the activator console.  For example, the below actually ran 6 tests in my package, but the results say 0 0 0 0 :

> [finbot] $ test-only com.myapp.finbot.model.*
>   [info] Updating {file:/Users/todd/workspace/finbot/}root...
>   [info] Resolving com.typesafe.trace#trace-sigar-libs;0.1.6 ...
>   [info] Done updating.
>   09:09:07.488 default [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.t.c.j.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner - >
>
> ................
>
> [info] o.h.v.i.u.Version - HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.0.3.Final
>   [debug] c.r.f.g.c.BatchConfiguration - ********************************** Step Created **********************************
>   [debug] c.r.f.g.c.BatchConfiguration - ********************************** Job Created **********************************
>   [info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0

Any ideas?

Comment: I think that is a [bug](https://github.com/sbt/junit-interface/issues/21) in sbt/junit-interface. You can try to use sbt 0.13.6 that supposedly fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading from sbt 0.13.5 to 0.13.6 as per @Salem's comment will fix the problem.

Comment: Worked for me as well!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use custom junit rule.

```
public class MyTest {
    // ...
    @Rule
    public CustomRule customRule = new CustomRule();
    // ...
}

public class CustomRule extends TestWatcher {
    @Override
    public Statement apply(final Statement base,
            final Description description) {
        return new Statement() {
            @Override
            public void evaluate() throws Throwable {
                try {
                    // before test execution
                    base.evaluate(); // test execution
                    // test succeeded
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // test failed
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```